# Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Tags: android, android-listview

I am writing a program in which i am trying to open that particular item in ProductInformationActivity.java which i have clicked on ListView Item Row, 
but whenever i click on Item Row, i am getting **Unfortunately App has Stopped**

*Error: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""*

**CartAdapter.java:**

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_cart, null);
        vi.setClickable(true);
        vi.setFocusable(true);
        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {               
            HashMap<String, String> prod = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(position);
            Intent mViewCartIntent = new Intent
                    (activity,com.era.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity.class);             
            mViewCartIntent.putExtra("product", prod);
            activity.startActivity(mViewCartIntent);                
        }
    });
```

**Logcat says:**

```
      04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.era.restaurant.versionoct/com.era.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at com.era.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity.onCreate(ProductInformationActivity.java:77)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-27 04:25:01.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1214):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: There's something wrong in your code. Why do you create an empty map and then reassign the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to pack the product item to the `Intent`'s bundle for example but this means your product's class should implement `Serializable` (to use `putSerializable()`) or `Parcelable`.
But you could use a more easy way - create `public static` field of type `Product` in your `ProductInformationActivity` and all you gonna need to do is just to instantiate it before calling the `ProductInformationActivity` and thats all. Like

```
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {               
                HashMap<String, String> product = new HashMap<String, String>();
                ProductInformationActivity.product = Constant.wishproducts.get(position);
                // startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),ProductInformationActivity.class));
                Intent mViewCartIntent = new Intent(activity,ProductInformationActivity.class);
                activity.startActivity(mViewCartIntent);                                                           
            }
```

Comment: It's a generally bad idea. Will work, but not nice at all. The HashMap is Serializable already so no problem passing it in intent.

Comment: but you need only one item from the hashmap. Why pass the whole map? And the HashMap is maybe serializable but it's contain is probably not so what do you expect from HashMap serializing? You'll get the serialize exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
CartActivity {


    //...

    private void initView() {
        //...
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id)
            {
                final HashMap<String, String> prod = Constant.wishproducts.get(pos);
                final Intent viewCartIntent = new Intent(CartActivity.this, ProductInformationActivity.class);
                viewCarIntent.putExtra("product", prod);
                startActivity(viewCartIntent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_cart, null);
    }
    //assign text, images, etc
    return vi;
}
```

Comment: i believe that your code is fine and best, but listview item row click is not responding, please help @DoctororDrive